# Change video view to full screen

Tags: android, layout, view, television

I know I've seen similar questions asked but I have yet to find a solution. I have an app for Android TV box that starts with the video playing in small view defined in my main xml. I wish to make the view full screen. I have tried setting the height and width using something like

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            video.setLayoutParams(params);
```

but no matter what I set the width and height to, the video view size doesn't change, it does move on the screen but that's all. I also saw threads mention creating a new activity with a new layout (full screen) and passing the instance of the video view, but  am unsure on how to pass the instance. Any help on getting the view to go full screen would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Posting xml. As requested here is part of the xml that includes the video view. As shown the video is wrapped in a linearlayout set to the size of a preview. If clicked I want the video to take up full screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.yaadspice.epgtv.Activity.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="DATE"
        android:textColor="@color/lb_tv_white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/desc"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="1200dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#00008B"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.428"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/videocontainer"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/overhanglogoplus"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/lb_tv_white"
        android:text="HOLDER"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/videocontainer"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/videocontainer"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/desc"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >



    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/videoView" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just set VideoView to `MATCH_PARENT` and the parent is the root of view tree? Or could you post the xml(include video view) to help others understand what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was over thinking it. Using the below, I was able to set the video size to whatever I needed.

```
LinearLayout container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.videocontainer);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params= (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();
params.width=720;
            params.height=1280;
container.setLayoutParams(params);
```